# Android- Setting width of a TextView to left of either button-1 or button-2

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

**Background:**
I've a `TextView` and two (custom) buttons to the right of the `TextView`. The 2 buttons and the `TextView` are included in a Single `RelativeLayout`. Now, at any point of time, either button-1 or button-2 will be *visible*. Since I won't be knowing which button will be visible, in my code for both buttons, I've added

```
android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/MyTextView"
```

property in the XML file. Which works fine. This places the button based on the position (and width) of the `TextView`.

**The issue:**
After language change, I have to change the width of the TextView based on the width of the Button to its right. I tried `minWidth/maxWidth` for both the buttons and the `TextView` as well, but they still don't allow dynamic resizing of the `TextView` based on the button's width.

Is there anyway where I can specify:

```
android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button1 | @+id/button2"
```

i.e, `TextView` to left of either button-1 or button-2. So that the text view will be aligned based on the button to the right?

**Note:**
I prefer a solution that needs changing the XML Layout file (static) rather than adding code in java (activity) file.

Comment: I came across this the other day and my research pointed towards it not being possible. I ended up nesting `LinearLayout` views inside the `RelativeLayout`, one with both `Button`s and the other with the `TextView`. The `LinearLayout`s can then be positioned relative to eachother. Would that work for you?

Comment: @CodeMonkey - I don't think that would work for me.. I am in no position to change the existing code.. :P

Comment: haha OK. That makes it a bit tricky. The change is fairly trivial, as is your suggested change of the `android:layout_toLeftOf`.

Comment: @Developer3820116 - Not anymore :P

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can keep the two buttons in a `RelativeLayout` and place that `RelativeLayout` in another `RelativeLayout`, then put the `TextView` as `alignLeft` of `RelativeLayout`:

Sample code from my app: You will need to modify as per your own

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/header_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">        

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/image_container"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/settings_img"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dip"
            android:contentDescription="@string/setting_desc"
            android:src="@drawable/top_settings"
            android:visibility="gone" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/logout_img"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/settings_img"
            android:contentDescription="@string/logout_desc"
            android:src="@drawable/top_quit"
            android:visibility="gone" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/image_container"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/logo_desc"
        android:src="@drawable/top_logo" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

So your views will adjust fine while any of the `ImageView` is visible.

Comment: It worked.. hadn't thought about putting the 2 buttons in another **Relativelayout**. Thanks :P

Comment: Goodie :) happy coding

Comment: @TheLostMind Thanks for the bounty. I'm sure you have your reasons for picking this answer. I can't see why - the xml sample makes little sense. It isn't setup according to your scenario - `You will need to modify as per your own` - Okay. The real problem - it doesn't even _do_ what mysticmagic indicates it does - ImageView with `@id/logo` is `toRightOf` a container that in itself has `alignParentRight` property? _Under what circumstance will this ImageView be **on the screen**?_ The answer also doesn't account for the `TextView` getting flushed right given the `wrap-content` width parameter.

Comment: Sorry if this seems excessively critical. I would have liked some explanation in the answer - for example - why the poster chose `RL over FL`. Or, even read my answer before posting theirs, based on the same idea. Thanks for the interesting question though.

Comment: @Vikram I didn't read your answer before posting the answer. I had faced the similar issue in last to last week, and just posted my xml for idea. And RelativeLayout is preferred by me as I find it a bit simple than playing with FrameLayout (May be because I didn't use FrameLayout much till now.) And it was `toLeftOf`, I corected that. Thanks for pointing it out. :).

Comment: @MysticMagic Hi, its totally fine. Although, I was saying something different. Its kind of redundant to post an answer that suggests the same(probably just my opinion) approach as an already posted answer. No problem though. As I said before, I apologize for being this critical.

Answer (score 6):

> The issue : After language change, I have to change the width of the TextView based on the width of the Button to its right. I tried minWidth/maxWidth for both the buttons and the TextView as well, but they still don't allow dynamic resizing of the TextView based on the button's width.

Okay.

Here we go:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/fl" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@id/fl"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bb1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="HELLO 1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bb2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="HELLO 2" />

    </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

What's happening?

We have grouped the `Buttons` in a `FrameLayout`. So, your concern `Is there anyway where I can specify : android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button1 | @+id/button2"` has been addressed - now, we only need to tell the `TextView` to be on left of the `FrameLayout`.

Next, we have set the `TextView's` width to `match_parent`. This *is* necessary. If the `TextView's` width was set to be `wrap_content`, the `TextView` would appear to be right-aligned.

Plus, we need the `Buttons` to stick to the right edge (from what I could gather from your question). So, we set the `layout_alignParentRight="true"` attribute on the `FrameLayout`.

The `maxLines` and `ellipsize` attributes ensure that the text stays presentable.

If I somehow misunderstood the question, please explain in comment(s) below.

And that's pretty much it.

Comment: So dumb of me.. hadn't thought about it.. This didn't work for me with *FrameLayout*, but it did work for me with another *RelativeLayout* containing the 2 buttons. Thanks :)

Comment: @TheLostMind I suggested the `FrameLayout` keeping in mind what you said: `...at any point of time, either button-1 or button-2 will be visible`. `FrameLayout` is the most efficient of android's viewgroups - `RelativeLayout` being the least. And I can't say why `FrameLayout` isn't working for you. What's strange is that the accepted answer is a re-iteration of mine. In any case, good luck :)

Comment: I am awarding you the bounty because your answer is *complete* with all details :).

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using a `LinearLayout` with a `layout_weight` property on the TextView. I have made a basic example of how you would implement this.

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.test;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final Button btnOne = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnOne);
        final Button btnTwo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnTwo);

        final Button btnHideOne = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnHideOne);
        final Button btnHideTwo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnHideTwo);
        final Button btnShowAll = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnShowAll);

        btnHideOne.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                btnOne.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });

        btnHideTwo.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                btnTwo.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });

        btnShowAll.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                btnOne.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                btnTwo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="16dp"
    tools:context="${packageName}.${activityClass}" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#979797"
            android:text="Text Text Text" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnOne"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Normal" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnTwo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Long Text" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnHideOne"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="Hide Button 1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnHideTwo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hide Button 2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnShowAll"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Show All" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I can't change the layout type now.. *too much dependency* with other parts of the app. I was wondering if one or more properties of the layout could be changed to achieve what I want.

Answer (score 0):

If you can modify the code, you can programmatically update which button the TextView is positioned relative to.

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.LEFT_OF, _BUTTON_ID_);
```

Comment: thats what I am doing currently :P

Comment: If that's the case, I can't think of anything else beyond converting the RelativeLayout to a LinearLayout.

Answer (score 0):

I did the following to fix the issue :

1. Created a `RelativeLayout` in the XML file and added the buttons (button-1 and button-2) inside it. The `RelativeLayout` has the following properties :

   ```
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_alignParentRight="true" 
       and Id
   ```
2. Added  `android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/relativelayoutID"` to the `TextView` .